# Date format in Marklogic for JSON Documents

Tags: json, timezone, marklogic, marklogic-8

I am having JSON docs with date in them, and I am trying to create a range index. When I do the ISO8601 format like this

```
2015-11-02T00:00:00-0600
```

I get the following error

```
IndexerEnv::putRangeIndex: XDMP-RANGEINDEX: Range index error: date "2015-11-02T00:00:00-0600": XDMP-LEXVAL: Invalid lexical value "2015-11-02T00:00:00-0600"
```

I thought it needs to be in UTC time and also needs a 'Z' in the end indicating Zulu time zone, so I forced for testing the time to be as follows

```
2015-11-02T00:00:00Z
```

I still get the same error..

```
IndexerEnv::putRangeIndex: XDMP-RANGEINDEX: Range index error: date "2015-11-02T00:00:00Z": XDMP-LEXVAL: Invalid lexical value "2015-11-02T00:00:00Z"
```

What is wrong here ? and also another question, does Marklogic understand dates only when we add 'Z' (Zulu timezone) in the date ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you all, found my error..

For types other than `xs:string`, I am not supposed to add the collation parameter to the sort-order.. Changed this to

```
<sort-order type="xs:dateTime" collation="http://marklogic.com/collation/" direction="ascending">
    <field name="concept_createdDate"/>
</sort-order>
```

to

```
<sort-order type="xs:dateTime" direction="ascending">
    <field name="concept_createdDate"/>
</sort-order>
```

and all worked

Answer (score 5):

Is your range index created with the proper data type?

The error tells me you have created a range index of datatype date and your trying to push a dateTime into a date range.
Try changing the definition of the range index from type date to type dateTime.

HTH,

Peter

Comment: This is the full format spec of the date format used in MarkLogic: http://books.xmlschemata.org/relaxng/ch19-77041.html, and this the one for dateTime: http://books.xmlschemata.org/relaxng/ch19-77049.html. So, it is the time part bothering you, and not the timezone. Unfortunately, MarkLogic won't allow you to index a dateTime pattern with a date index..